# View Controller presented from iMessage Application gets covered by iMessage top bar unlike the parent

Tags: ios, swift, imessage, imessage-extension

I noticed that positioning a toolbar under an iMessage bar was difficult because spawned view controllers seem to begin being drawn in the space that the top iMessage bar rests. Using a fixed distance from the top of 64 does not work since iPhone 5s' iMessage bar is 44 pixels in height.

I then realized that this is only an issue when presenting a view controller and that the first view controller or the root view controller actually begins being rendered below the iMessage top bar. I would like to know if there is either way to detect the height, or if there is a way to make spawned view controllers apply similar layouting as the root controller for an iMessage Application.

Here's some screeshots showing the problem. Note the small gap between toolbar and top bar. This is because of iPhone 5s' shorter iMessage top bar height.

**iPhone 5S showing the gap**

[image: 5s device with gap between top bar and nav bar]

**No gap between toolbar and top bar on 6s/larger devices:**

[image: 6s device with no gap between top bar and nav bar]

I coded a sample app to show that spawned view controllers begin being drawn in the same spot as the iMessage top bar.

**Initial/Parent view controller with a < 10 pixels of top constraint.**

[image: Sample app showing that parent controller begins rendering below imessage top bar]

**Child with < 10 pixels of top constraint on pink button.**

[image: Sample app showing that spawned View controllers begins rendering at the same location as imessage top bar]

**Screenshot of sample story boards.**

[image: Storyboard showing VCs are similar distance from top]

Answer (score 0):

Today I had almost the same issue, I present ViewController from deeplink and some navigation bar pop up .. :)

To resolve the issue I embed NavigationController in the ViewController and I hide the navigation bar in viewWillAppear.

`self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: true)`

Hope this will help.
Wish you all the best.